# How to select rows based on the sum of values in one column meeting a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores the types of interactions a client has with a webpage (simplified for the sake of clarity). These columns are: month, client id, interaction type, number of times an interaction was made

```
   month    clientId   interactionType   numberOfInteractions  
 --------- ---------- ----------------- ---------------------- 
  2020-01        123   click                                1  
  2020-01        123   scroll                               2  
  2020-01        123   hover                                1  
  2020-01         89   click                                12 
  2020-01         65   hover                                6  
  2020-01         65   scroll                               8  
  2020-02         89   click                                12 
  2020-02         89   scroll                               9
```

What I would like to do on a monthly basis is only select the entries where the total number of interactions is greater than a threshold value per client.

For example, if I pick a value of 4, only entries for a client with the sum of interactions across scroll, hover and click greater than or equal to 4 will be selected. Applying this logic to my table, all 8 entries would be returned.

However if I change the threshold to 10, only the following entries would be returned (as the sum of numberOfInteractions for each interaction type, per client, per month, is above 10)

```
   month    clientId   interactionType   numberOfInteractions  
 --------- ---------- ----------------- ---------------------- 
  2020-01         89   click                                12 
  2020-01         65   hover                                6  
  2020-01         65   scroll                               8  
  2020-02         89   click                                12 
  2020-02         89   scroll                               9
```

My thinking of a solution for this is to create a cte that sums up numberOfInteractions grouped by month and clientId, and then join this to the original table. E.g.

```
with temp as (
select 
   i.*,
   sum(numberOfInteractions)
from
   interactions a
group by
   a.month,
   a.clientId,
   a.interactionType,
   a.numberOfInteractions
)
select
   *
from
   interactions b
join
   temp on temp.month = b.month and temp.clientId = b.clientId
```

Can anyone recommend a query that allows for this kind of filtering on a aggreagate level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             sum(numberOfInteractions) over (partition by month, clientId) as month_cnt
      from interactions i
     ) i
where month_cnt > 4;
```